# Server does not recognize second VirtualBox Adapter

Tags: 10.04, server, virtualbox, networking

I have installed Ubuntu Server 10.04 as a guest operating system under VirtualBox 3.2.10. My host system is Ubuntu 9.04

I have configured two network adapters for the guess (a NAT one and a host-only one)

The NAT one is recognized without problems by the guest, but in order to recognize the host-only adapter I have to run `sudo dhclient`, thus making it impossible to run the guest
in headless mode.

I'm sure I am forgetting something.

When i run `ifconfig` right after login I see two interfaces (**eth0** and **lo**), then after running `sudo dhclient` I see three interfaces (**eth0**, **eth1** and **lo**)

So the question is: How can I make ubuntu to get the IP from the second adapter at boot time in order to be capable of running headless and accessing it via ssh?

Comment: Sorry, but I've got to ask: Did you run `ifconfig` or `ifconfig -a` ??

Comment: @Jeremy: `ifconfig` but then i see your question and ran `ifconfig -a`. But the output of both commands is (at least for me) **exactly** the same. Anyway it appears to be a [bug](http://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/4038) in VirtualBox DHCP server implementation.

Comment: Kk, I can't really help you, just wanted to check if the interface was present, but down. Good luck! You could try Oracle <shudder> (Sun) support, if it's a bug in VBox, they'll be all over it.

Comment: your comment on the dhclient saved me, i was wondering why i cant get adapter 2 to work in any situation.  this now has it enrolled, thanks.  I have a RHEL so not able to follow @cvrse suggestions.

Answer (score 20):

have you got the interface configured in `/etc/network/interfaces` ? if not add the lines

```
 auto eth1
 iface eth1 inet dhcp
```

and restart

Comment: If you would like to avoid the system restart, you can use "sudo service networking restart" instead.

Comment: To figure out what interfaces are available, use `ip link`. It'll show you the interfaces you have. You can then run the commands above, replacing `eth1` with what you saw in the previous command

Comment: @Highmastdon - thanks! That was the missing link for me. systemd went from ens3 (the only network adapter aside from lo) - to ens9, and I was trying this^ answer with ens4. Super helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 10):

To find your available interfaces use:

```
ip link
```

this will show you the interfaces you have, like so:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:1d:bd:93 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: enp0s8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:c2:c1:92 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Now add the last interface to the interfaces (in this case `enp0s8`)

```
vi /etc/network/interfaces
```

Type in `[i]` to edit (and move with arrow keys or **before [i]** `hjkl` (left, down, up, right))

```
auto enp0s8
iface enp0s8 inet dhcp
```

Save and close with [esc] `:wq`

Comment: or just use nano instead of vi! :D

Answer (score 9):

For latest versions (18.04) of the Ubuntu, network settings are stored in
`/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml`.

1. Get device name with `dmesg | grep enp` (enp could be replaced to your device type).
2. Then insert (for device named enp0s8):

   ```
   enp0s8:
     addresses: []
     dhcp4: true
     optional: true
   ```
3. Then use `sudo netplan apply` to apply changes.

Comment: This one solves the issue with ubuntu 18.04 VM.

Comment: Worked for me too. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS** uses *Netplan* for network configuration by default. The default configuration file in that case is `/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml`.

- Get the device name with `ip link`
- Insert the device in the file `/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml` (for example, `enp0s8`):

```
enp0s8:
  addresses: [192.168.2.89/24] # example
  gateway4: 192.168.2.1
  dhcp4: true
```

- Run `sudo netplan apply` to apply changes.

Check [this link](https://linuxhint.com/setup_static_ip_address_ubuntu/) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

```
vi /etc/network/interfaces
```

press <kbd>i</kbd> and add the text

```
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp
```

press <kbd>esc</kbd> and type `:wq` and <kbd>enter</kbd>

Then do:

```
/etc/init.d/networking restart
```

Answer (score 0):

**For Ubuntu 18.04 server**

list available network interfaces

```
ip link
```

return

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:1d:bd:93 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: enp0s8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:c2:c1:92 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

configure interface enp0s8 with netplan: edit `/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml` and add the following to the networks list

```
enp0s8:
  dhcp4: true
  optional: true
```